# How do I update my database with mysqli and javascript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, mysqli

I have a website which basically is an audioplayer and an integrated lyricviewer on screen, which the user should be able to sync with the music they hear playing. I only have one problem, and that is; How on earth do I, from a javascript function, call a mysqli update statement? When the user clicks a save button, content gets thrown into a div, which I want the PHP after the JavaScript has been run to take that content and put it into a database.

What is the best way to do that?

Why doesn't this work?

```
        function saveinPHP() {
        //alert("Came here");
        //var superstr = $( "#savelyric" ).text();
        var superstr = 'lol';
        $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "includes/sendlyrics.php",
        data: superstr,
        cache: false,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
        success:  function(data){
            alert("---"+data);
            alert("Settings has been updated successfully." + data + "~~~" + superstr);
            //window.location.reload(true);
        }
    });
    }
```

And then the PHP:

```
    <?php 
include ('db_connect.php');

$data = $_POST['data'];

    $query = "UPDATE song SET time=". $data ." WHERE id='1'";
    mysqli_query($query);
?>
```

Comment: https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/

Comment: you should have a look, what "ajax" is

Comment: Not heard so much about Ajax before, but I can check it out. Thanks!

Comment: @Kevkong Can you look at why this does not work? Code Looked like a mess, look at the post instead...

Comment: **Danger**: You are **vulnerable to [SQL injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com/)** that you need to [defend](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/best-way-to-prevent-sql-injection-in-php) yourself from.

Answer (score 0):

Write PHP in a totally separate dedicated file that takes POST variables, constructs an SQL query, and inserts them into a database. Then have your JavaScript function send the data to this PHP file using a POST request.

JavaScript in the browser cannot interact with the database. It can only send GET/POST requests to the server which can catch those requests and put the attached data into the database.

Answer (score 0):

**First**, when you specify a string as `data`, jQuery will send it as is.

The string you are using `"lol"` is not formatted in either of the standard formats for POST data that are understood by PHP.

`$_POST`, therefore, has no data in it.

Pass jQuery an object instead:

```
data: { data: superstr }
```

**Second**, `false` is not a content-type of either of the standard formats mentioned above. jQuery will use an appropriate content-type by default. Remove this override:

```
contentType: false,
```

**Third**, `processData: false,` will break the conversion of the object into form encoded data. Remove it.

**Fourth**, strings in SQL must be quoted. You aren't quoting `data`.

```
 $query = "UPDATE song SET time='$data' WHERE id='1'";
```

Note this is still vulnerable to SQL injection and you should [fix that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/best-way-to-prevent-sql-injection-in-php).

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer! I'd like to ask, the thing about objects. "Lol" was only a test string, the real thing I'd like to send is `var superstr = $( "#savelyric" ).text();`. Is that already an object, or how do I make it one?

Comment: No, it is a string. You do the same thing as I did for the previous string.

Comment: It's everything I spotted. Look at your JavaScript error console. Check the request and response in your browser's developer tools Net tab. Check your server log for errors.